# ctags regex for multiple declarations in one line

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm writing a .ctags file for a custom language... Like most languages, it allows for multiple variable declarations in one line.. i.e.:

```
int a, b, c;
```

I have a basic regex which recognizes 'a':

```
--regex-mylang=/^[ \t]*int[ \t]*([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/\1/v,variable/
```

How do I modify this to have it match 'b' and 'c', as well? I can't find anything in ctags documentation that deals with multiple matches in a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through this for a few hours, I'm convinced it can't be done.  No matter what, the regular expression will only expand to one tag per line.  Even if you put \1 \2 \3 ... as the expansion, that would just cause a tag consisting of multiple matches, instead of one tag per match.

It parses the C example correctly because inside the ctags source code it uses an actual code parser, not a regexp.

Answer (score 6):

The **latest** Universal-ctags can capture them.

```
[jet@localhost]/tmp% cat input.x 
int a, b, c;

[jet@localhost]/tmp% cat x.ctags 
--langdef=X
--map-X=.x

--kinddef-X=v,var,variables
--_tabledef-X=main
--_tabledef-X=vardef

--_mtable-regex-X=main/int[ \t]+//{tenter=vardef}
--_mtable-regex-X=main/.//

--_mtable-regex-X=vardef/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\1/v/
--_mtable-regex-X=vardef/;//{tleave}
--_mtable-regex-X=vardef/.//


[jet@localhost]/tmp% u-ctags --options=x.ctags -o - ./input.x 
a   ./input.x   /^int a, b, c;$/;"  v
b   ./input.x   /^int a, b, c;$/;"  v
c   ./input.x   /^int a, b, c;$/;"  v
```

See https://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/optlib.html#advanced-pattern-matching-with-multiple-regex-tables for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do parsing with a regex, which is not generally possible.  Parsing requires the equivalent of storing information on a stack, but a regular expression can embody only a finite number of different states.

Answer (score 0):

it can be partialy done with the [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) and with the help of  `{_multiline=N}` and `{scope}` flag. The `N` is group number which position is saved in generated `tags` file.
For more information look here: [docs/optlib.rst](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/blob/master/docs/optlib.rst)

**Configuration:** `mylang.ctags`

```
--langmap=mylang:.txt
--regex-mylang=/^[[:blank:]]*(int)[[:blank:]]/\1/{placeholder}{scope=set}{_multiline=1}
--regex-mylang=/(;)/\1/{placeholder}{scope=clear}
--regex-mylang=/[[:blank:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)[[:blank:]]*,?/\1/v,variable/{_multiline=1}{scope=ref}
```

**Test file:** `test.txt`

```
void main() {
   int   a, b, c, d;
}
```

Generate tags with: `ctags --options=mylang.ctags test.txt`

**Generated `tags` file:**

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_MODE   u-ctags /u-ctags or e-ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Universal Ctags Team    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Universal Ctags /Derived from Exuberant Ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   https://ctags.io/   /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   0.0.0   /cb4476eb/
a   test.txt    /^   int   a, b, c, d;$/;"  v
b   test.txt    /^   int   a, b, c, d;$/;"  v
c   test.txt    /^   int   a, b, c, d;$/;"  v
d   test.txt    /^   int   a, b, c, d;$/;"  v
int test.txt    /^   int   a, b, c, d;$/;"  v
main    test.txt    /^void main() {$/;" v
void    test.txt    /^void main() {$/;" v
```

Comment: Don't work. I get an error ```ctags: Warning: Unknown language "mylang:.txt" in "langmap" option
ctags: Unknown language "mylang" in "regex-mylang" option```

Answer (score -4):

```
--regex-perl=/^\s*?use\s+(\w+[\w\:]*?\w*?)/\1/u,use,uses/
--regex-perl=/^\s*?require\s+(\w+[\w\:]*?\w*?)/\1/r,require,requires/
--regex-perl=/^\s*?has\s+['"]?(\w+)['"]?/\1/a,attribute,attributes/
--regex-perl=/^\s*?\*(\w+)\s*?=/\1/a,aliase,aliases/
--regex-perl=/->helper\(\s?['"]?(\w+)['"]?/\1/h,helper,helpers/
--regex-perl=/^\s*?our\s*?[\$@%](\w+)/\1/o,our,ours/
--regex-perl=/^=head1\s+(.+)/\1/p,pod,Plain Old Documentation/
--regex-perl=/^=head2\s+(.+)/-- \1/p,pod,Plain Old Documentation/
--regex-perl=/^=head[3-5]\s+(.+)/---- \1/p,pod,Plain Old Documentation/
```

Comment: How is that an answer? Does it do any kind of multiple matching? Can anyone explain what this does?